# How do I make several things in a ASP.NET event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="selectedRecievedValue" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

I then have a TextBox with a onfocus event

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value") %>' CssClass="rowSpildValue"
 onfocus='<%# Eval("data_id", "document.getElementById(\"selectedDataID\").value = 
 \"{0}\"; document.getElementById(\"selectedFieldID\").value = \"rowSpildValue\";") %>'
 OnTextChanged="SpildChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ID="rowSpildValue" />
```

This already runs some code, but how would I add another line of code that would set my

```
HiddenField = Eval("deliveredValue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value") %>' CssClass="rowSpildValue"
    onfocus='<%# Eval(
        "data_id", 
        "document.getElementById(\"selectedDataID\").value = \"{0}\";" +
        "document.getElementById(\"selectedFieldID\").value = \"rowSpildValue\";") + 
                Eval(
        "deliveredValue",
        "document.getElementById(\"selectedRecievedValue\").value=\"{0}\"") %>'
    OnTextChanged="SpildChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ID="rowSpildValue" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add all the JavaScript code you like just separate the lines with a semicolon **;**

Anyway I would go down this way as it can be very odd to debug and maintain (it is also not cross platform)

I would suggest you to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

Extract your JavaScript to a JS function

```
<script>
   function onFocus(data_id) {
     document.getElementById("selectedDataID").value = data_id;          
     document.getElementById("selectedFieldID").value = "rowSpildValue"; 
     document.getElementById("selectedRecievedValue").value = <%# Eval("deliveredValue") %>;
   }
</script>
```

and then set that as the event handler

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value") %>' CssClass="rowSpildValue"
 onfocus='<%# Eval("data_id", "onFocus(\"{0}\");") .../>
```